# Native Google Reader clients for OS X?

Tags: google-apps, rss

Are there any good Google Reader clients for OS X?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Reeder for Mac](http://reederapp.com/mac/) is pretty awesome.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

There are several RSS readers and some can sync with google Reader

This includes
[NetNewsWire](http://netnewswireapp.com/mac/)

Other clients include
[Vienna RSS](http://www.vienna-rss.com/)

Comment: NetNewsWire works great.  I've been using it for years.  Its been around since before Google Reader, and switched away from their own synchronization implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **[Gruml](http://www.grumlapp.com/)**. It's still in beta and hasn't convinced me to switch from the web version, but it's pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed [Cappuccino](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/cappuccino/id492594411?mt=12) and it looks nice. Simple to use, fast and syncs with Google Reader.